# How to parse a Gemfile like file

Tags: ruby, parsing, dsl

I need to write a custom syntax for a template engine.

Like this:

https://github.com/pietbrauer/cocoapods-generate-command/blob/master/README.md

Example from the README:

```
# template
git :init

# questions
prefix = ask('What prefix should be used for your files?')
prefix = prefix.uppercase

# add pods
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.0'

pod_group :SampleTests do
  pod 'OCMock'
end
```

Whats the best approach for this? Would one write a custom DSL or a parser to execute ruby code.

Comment: Could you give an example of the syntax you are targeting? A DSL can be simple and clean to implement but a parser is more powerful. Which approach works better really depends on the syntax.

Comment: I added some examples from the README

Comment: The tutorial in  [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) is all about creating an internal DSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you posted, I'd definitely look at writing [an internal Ruby DSL](http://softwarebyjosh.com/2012/01/08/How-To-Write-Your-Own-DSL.html).  The syntax looks like valid Ruby code to me, it'll be as easy as it gets.

Comment: I experimented with this. But sadly didn't got it running with an external file.

Comment: Posting what you tried that didn't work sounds like a perfect StackOverflow question.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted to know if I may approached it wrong. How would I run the file containing the DSL?

Comment: Look at the [eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) and [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) methods.  They'll execute Ruby code stored in a string object.